# Maven releases and snapshot in pom file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to build a pipeline with jenkins, I will get the code from SVN repository and after, build the project and send to the nexus.
I'm thinking doing the following approach:

1° get the code from SVN (trunk folder)

2° compile code

3° send to nexus to snapshot  (1.2-SNAPSHOT) and release (1.2) folders (war file)

4° go to svn, increase the version of pom file with snapshot name, like 1.3-SNAPSHOT (trunk folder)

What do u think about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Approach looks fine but this post will fall more into opinion-based category.

Comment: I can't find that category.

Comment: Sorry, I think i was not clear in my comment. What i meant to say was that your question might not attract answers because it's opinion-based.

Comment: You can create the release using the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin) and the [Jenkins Release Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/release/).